# complexType with Simple XML framework?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, simple-framework

how do i translate a complexType in an .xsd file to a SimpleXML annotated class structure.  here's an example that's been translated to JAXB using xjc.exe.  not sure what the equivalent annotation would be for the Simple framework.

schema:

```
<xsd:element name="PaymentTxnID">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="IDTYPE">
                <xsd:attribute name="useMacro" type="MACROTYPE"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

JAXB generated:

```
public static class PaymentTxnID {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "useMacro")
    protected String useMacro;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getUseMacro() {
        return useMacro;
    }

    public void setUseMacro(String value) {
        this.useMacro = value;
    }
}
```

how can i represent complexTypes with Simple?

Answer (score 2):

it appears that `@Text` annotation is the answer.  view the javadoc [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/).  the example was found in [Blaise Doughan's blog entry](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html) under the section "Mapping Objects to Simple Content".

Simple framework translation:

```
public static class PaymentTxnID {
    @Text
    protected String value;
    @Attribute(name = "useMacro")
    protected String useMacro;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getUseMacro() {
        return useMacro;
    }

    public void setUseMacro(String value) {
        this.useMacro = value;
    }
}
```